# Rotate Image and View Next Page

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, picturebox

I’m using WinForms for my application. I’m building an image viewer. My application opens image documents (.tif) files. The application has the ability to go to the next page.

The issue is, that every time I try to rotate the image and click next, the image stays on the same page but the page number increments.

Why can’t I see the images when it’s on rotate?

How can I rotate the image and go to the next page?

In the link below I've provided a test tif document for testing purposes: 
http://www.filedropper.com/sampletifdocument5pages

My Code:

```
    FileStream _stream;
    Image _myImg; // setting the selected tiff
    string _fileName;
    private int intCurrPage = 0; // defining the current page
    private int intTotalPages = 0;


    private void Open_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lblFile.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            // Before loading you should check the file type is an image

            if (_myImg == null)
            {
                _fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
                File.Copy(@lblFile.Text, _fileName);
                _stream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(_stream);
            }

            //pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(750, 1100);

            // Reset the current page when loading a new image.
            intCurrPage = 1;
            intTotalPages = pictureBox1.Image.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);

            lblNumPages.Text = intTotalPages.ToString();
            lblCurrPage.Text = "1";


        }
     }

    private void NextPage_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (intCurrPage <= (intTotalPages - 1))
        {
            if(Radio_90_Rotate.Checked)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
            }
            if(Radio_180_Rotate.Checked)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
            }

            // Directly increment the active frame within the image already in the PictureBox
            pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, intCurrPage);

            //page increment (Go to next page)
            intCurrPage++;


            // Refresh the PictureBox so that it will show the currently active frame
            pictureBox1.Refresh();

            lblCurrPage.Text = intCurrPage.ToString();

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try to increment the frame (pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame) higher in the function, before calling the RotateFlip (pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip).

Comment: I just tried it. It does the same thing. @Don

Comment: I just tested the code and it does update and rotate the image when going to the next page.   However it does NOT rotate it when the radiobuttons are changed - for that you would need to register to those events. Also When it gets to the last page of the tif file it does not change anything due to the IF (if (intCurrPage <= (intTotalPages - 1)))

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try it out again right now. So that i understand correctly, did you put the if statements for the radio buttons under the intCurrPage++ when testing? @Don

Comment: Actually I copied your code exactly as is in your question.

Comment: That's strange. Every time I click next, ( while a rotate Radio button is checked) The current image keeps rotating. For me it does not display the next page if a radio button is checked. @Don

Comment: Are you sure the pages within your tif file are not duplicated?  Perhaps it's going to the next page which is the same image?  What does your page indicators say at each step?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is duplicated. When the radio buttons are not selected then the tif documents can display the images properly. As soon as one of the radio buttons is selected it keeps rotating the current image, and the current page number goes up as well. @Don

Comment: The strange thing is, if i select one of the radio buttons and then decide to clear it, and click on the next page button. The current page number increments but the next image or an updated image doesn't display.

Comment: I was mistaken - sorry, the page was not changing - my source image was just so wide it looked different on the other side.  I changed the code and will post it the answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97446/discussion-between-don-and-taji01).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RotateFlip` function will change the source image and flatten it to only one page.  This means we need to make copies each time you view a new page that has rotation applied.

In this solution, I use the source image and simply change pages when no rotation is applied.  But when rotation is set, then a Image copy is made for each page and then the rotation is applied to the copy only.

Using your sample image it takes time to load each page.  So I implemented a simple label message to let the user know it's working.

Also, you may consider looking into classes prebuilt for tiff files like:  https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/

```
private Image _Source = null;
private int _TotalPages = 0;
private int _CurrentPage = 0;

private void Frm_TiffViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_WaitMessage.Visible = false;

    // These two options can be adjusted as needed and probably should be set in the form control properties directly:
    pictureBox1.Size = new Size(750, 1100);
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
}

private void ShowProcessingImageLabel()
{
    lbl_WaitMessage.Visible = true;
    Application.DoEvents();
}

private void DisplayPage(int PageNumber, RotateFlipType Change)
{
    if (pictureBox1.Image != null && pictureBox1.Image != _Source)
    {
        // Release memory for old rotated image
        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
    }

    //  set the variable to null for easy GC cleanup
    pictureBox1.Image = null;

    _Source.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, PageNumber - 1);

    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(_Source);

    pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(Change);

    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}

private void DisplayPage(int PageNumber)
{
    ShowProcessingImageLabel();

    this.lblCurrPage.Text = PageNumber.ToString();

    // You could adjust the PictureBox size here for each frame  OR adjust the image to fit the picturebox nicely.
    if (Radio_90_Rotate.Checked == true)
    {
        DisplayPage(PageNumber, RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        lbl_WaitMessage.Visible = false;
        return;
    }
    else if (Radio_180_Rotate.Checked == true)
    {
        DisplayPage(PageNumber, RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
        lbl_WaitMessage.Visible = false;
        return;
    }

    if (pictureBox1.Image != _Source)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            // Release memory for old copy and set the variable to null for easy GC cleanup
            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = _Source;
    }

    pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, PageNumber-1);

    pictureBox1.Refresh();

    lbl_WaitMessage.Visible = false;
}


private void Open_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Before loading you should check the file type is an image

        this._Source = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        _TotalPages = _Source.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);
        _CurrentPage = 1;

        lblCurrPage.Text = "1";
        lblFile.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        this.lblNumPages.Text = _TotalPages.ToString();

        DisplayPage(_CurrentPage);
    }
}

private void NextPage_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_CurrentPage < _TotalPages)
    {
        _CurrentPage++;
    }

    DisplayPage(_CurrentPage);
}

private void b_Previous_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_CurrentPage > 1)
    {
        _CurrentPage--;
    }

    DisplayPage(_CurrentPage);
}

private void Radio_90_Rotate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayPage(_CurrentPage);
}

private void Radio_180_Rotate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayPage(_CurrentPage);
}

private void Radio_0_Default_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayPage(_CurrentPage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks the application goes to the next page rotated once fine, but after that it has the same issue. Open file>click radio button>Next page(Good)> Click on Next page again (Something went wrong here). It kept rotating the same image again. @Don

Comment: Try moving the pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame(...) below the rotate functions.   I need a bigger multipage tiff file to test with.  I am making one now and will see how that works if you don't try it first.

Comment: I moved the pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame(...) below the rotate functions, and it didn't go to the next page. Here is a bigger tif document so you dont have to create one. http://www.filedropper.com/tiftestingdoc

Comment: It looks like the rotate command is changing the total number of pages.  I'm investigating.

Comment: I moved that conversation over to chat so we can talk further there:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97446/discussion-between-don-and-taji01

Comment: I have updated the answer to handle the concerns we discussed.

Comment: Thank you Don! Once again you've been so much help i really appreciate all your time and the comments you provided it really helps.

Answer (score 0):

I`m Created Custom Mode v3.1

```
 public Image _Image_v3_1_CustomMode(Image b1, float angle,float dx,float dy,float sx,float sy)

        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(b1.Width, b1.Height);

            using(Graphics ehack = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                ehack.RotateTransform(angle);
                ehack.TranslateTransform(dx, dy);
                ehack.ScaleTransform(sx, sy);
                ehack.DrawImage(b1, 0, 0);


                return bitmap;
            }


    }
```